# How To Make Form Field readonly via component?

Tags: angular, angular-formly

I have been using angular formly for creating dynamic forms. In My form I have used disable fields but those dependent fields means autofilled by some other input. But I submits my form these disable input field values are not added to form value. I also tried with form.getRawValue and It's not working, How can I get fields values which are must be set to readonly? I want to use readonly property in json but I don't know how to use it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.form.getRawValue();

I got it, The above line gives all values in form includes disable fields also.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has an inbuilt attribute read-only for an input tag, which works in these case.

```
<input readonly />
```

Make sure you validate the form before submitting, this property can be manipulated by opening dev tools and removing readonly tag from the input element.

Comment: It is in  angular formly I have to set readonly through json object only.